# SQLite VARCHAR default size

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, when I say:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    my_column VARCHAR 
);
```

without specifying the size of `VARCHAR`, what is the default size that is used?

I can't seem to find it at sqlite.org or figure out from my database file.

I know that SQLite doesn't enforce size when trying to stuff `varchar(500)` into `varchar(30)`, but are there tradeoffs in initial size specification and what are best practices?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

SQLite does not use sizes when declaring the `VARCHAR` type.  In fact, it almost doesn't use the type either.

You can store `TEXT` in an `INT` column in SQLite.  And SQLite will [never truncate](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9) a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Wow does it mean SQLite column stores a pointer to the actual data instead?

Comment: I don't know the exact storage mechanism that SQLite uses (one aspect of the "SQL contract" is that you assume nothing about the underlying storage mechanism) but I expect it uses variable length rows with the TEXT data stored in the row.

Answer (score 21):

From what I can gather, `VARCHAR` is the same as `TEXT`

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Also see http://www.sqlite.org/different.html#flex

Answer (score 11):

In SQLite, `Text` is the parent of `VARCHAR` and in the default installation is no different http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.