# create table query are not perform in android connect to SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
private static final String dbname="student.db";
private static final String tblname="detail";
private static final String c1="uname";
private static final String c2="id";
private static final String c3="pass";
private static final String c4="add";
private static final String c5="gender";
private static final String c6="sequrity";
private static final String c7="answer";


public Databasehelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, dbname, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String q= "create table "+tblname+"("
        +c1+" varchar(10),"
        +c2+" varchar(20),"
        +c3+" varchar(10),"
        +c4+" varchar(100),"
        +c5+" varchar(10),"
        +c6+" varchar(100),"
        +c7+" varchar(10))";

        db.execSQL(q);
}
```

in above coding in create table define Error

Comment: share you error log

Comment: it not define Error but when i run avd than  my application is unfortunatlly stoped ...   chaek mya create table query is right or not

Comment: Suggestion: Use the Room library. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Comment: There **is** an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: when i run this project it create only database not create table

Comment: just when your application is crashed go to Android monitor on the bottom of your android studio screen and paste what's on your logcat here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your logs. Also, you will want to clear the application data. For more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: please don't edit your question to be something completely different, rendering any older comments or answers obsolete

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query with this

```
"create table "+tblname+"("+c1+" TEXT, "+c2+" TEXT, "+c3+" TEXT, "+c4+" TEXT, "+c5+" TEXT, "+c6+" TEXT, "+c7+" TEXT)";
```

In SQLite TEXT is same as VARCHAR you can use TEXT [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788544/2809351).

You can also check commonly asked quetions for sqlite [here](https://sqlite.org/faq.html)

Comment: How does this help if VARCHAR is the same as TEXT?

Comment: VARCHAR is not same as TEXT, TEXT is same as VARCHAR. TEXT is super class for VARCHAR

Comment: There is no difference in what we said. There is no VARCHAR... Also, then documentation says *SQLite understands the column type of "VARCHAR(N)" to be the same as "TEXT"*

Comment: For portability with MySQL / PostgreSQL? I don't know. SQLite does not care about the value of N.

Comment: you can't choose a size for text but you can choose the size for varchar. Varchar is better to use for database optimization.

Comment: android doesn't matter with size specified, as @cricket_007 says

Answer (score 0):

`add` is a [sqlite keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). As such it cannot be used as an identifier such as a column name.

Rename that column to something that is not a keyword.

Comment: hurree     thankyou so much       my misteck is that    colum name is remane add is any key word